# how to do countplot of several excel sheet of same excel file using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, plot, count

https://github.com/mehenaaz/Employee_Attrition_Analysis/blob/main/Emp1.xlsx
I have an excel file with two different sheets named 'existing employee' and 'left employee'.Each has multiple same column names. I need to countplot of several excel sheets of the same excel file using python. Like I want to show the comparison of satisfaction level between 'existing employees and 'left employee' in countplot. how can I do it?
I want the result like this:[countplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5joPB.png)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

filename = 'Emp1.xlsx'

sheet = 'current_employee'
df1 = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name=sheet)
df1.boxplot(column='satisfaction_level')
plt.title(sheet)
plt.show()

sheet = 'left_employee'
df2 = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name=sheet)
df2.boxplot(column='satisfaction_level')
plt.title(sheet)
plt.show()
```

[image: plots]

---

**edit:** Formatted for subplots

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

filename = 'Emp1.xlsx'

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True)

sheet = 'current_employee'
df1 = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name=sheet)
ax1 = df1.boxplot(column='satisfaction_level',ax=axes[0])
ax1.title.set_text(sheet)

sheet = 'left_employee'
df2 = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name=sheet)
ax2 = df2.boxplot(column='satisfaction_level',ax=axes[1])
ax2.title.set_text(sheet)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I want the result in one fig...comparing the two same columns from two sheets.